# Sometimes it is necessary to show my dataframe to properly ask the question. How can I do that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to ask a question related to a DataFrame. I tried to add screenshots before but I got -3 reputation and it says I am not allowed to upload the image. What is the best way then. I am new to stack overflow. Please help.

Comment: generally, you should not post a screenshot of a DataFrame. It's better if you can post a portion of that DataFrame in plain text. That way people can copy that and feed to their code. Also, this should be asked on meta site.

Answer (score 1):

You could either provide the code the generate sample data or you could do `print(df)` and paste the result with code format as a part of your question. For us it is possible to copy a dataframe as text a load it into a proper dataframe. Usually you can provide less than 20 rows of sample data and that should be enough to replicate the desired output